# Present PHP data as 2 sets of paired Excel columns

Tags: php, arrays, excel, codeigniter, multiple-columns

Is there an easy way to split (break and continue) array values by two sides(i mean two columns)?

For example, i want to get data like the following table:

```
   A           B                C               D                 E
CellRow |  Sampling Time  |  Sample Type |  Sampling Time  |  Sample Type
=========================================================================
  12          17:42             Start          11:42            Random
  13          17:42             Start          12:42            Random
  14          18:42             Random         12:42            Random
  15          18:42             Random         13:42            Random
  16          19:42             Random         13:42            Random
  17          19:42             Random         14:42            Random
  18          20:42             Random         14:42            Random
  19          20:42             Random         15:42            Random
  20          21:42             Random         15:42            Random
  21          21:42             Random         16:42            Random
  22          22:42             Random         16:42            Random
  23          22:42             Random         17:42            Random
  24          23:42             Random         17:42            Random
  25          23:42             Random         18:08            End
  26          08:42             Random         18:08            End
  27          08:42             Random
  28          10:42             Random
  29          10:42             Random
  30          11:42             Random
```

And here is my code to export the data to excel file:

```
<?php

        $detail = $this->M_transactions->get_detail_byid($id);

        if(isset($detail)) {
            $totalDetail = count($detail); // for example totalDetail is 34, and above table is actually the real data
        } else {
            $totalDetail ='0';
        }

        // ====  setup display data  ====
        $row_percolumn = 19;   // MAX rows on table        

        if($totalDetail < $row_percolumn) {
            $worksheet = 1;
        } else {
            if(($totalDetail  % $row_percolumn) == 0) {
                $worksheet = $totalDetail / $row_percolumn;
            } else {
                $worksheet = floor(($totalDetail / $row_percolumn)) + 1;
            }
        }

        foreach($dtdetail as $dtdetail_row) {
            $sampling_time[]  = $dtdetail_row->sampling_time;
            $sample_type[]    = $dtdetail_row->sample_type;
        }

        for($i=0; $i < $worksheet; $i++) {
            $rowPage = 11; // start print detail after row 11 

            $start_detail = ($i * $row_percolumn);
            $finish_detail = (($i * $row_percolumn) + ($row_percolumn - 1));

            $data = $start_detail;

             while ($data <= $finish_detail) {
                $rowPage++;

                if(isset($sampling_time[$data])) { 
                  $dt_sampling_time[$data] = $sampling_time[$data]; 
                } else {
                  $dt_sampling_time[$data] = ''; 
                }

                if(isset($sample_type[$data])) { 
                  $dt_sample_type[$data] = $sample_type[$data]; 
                } else {
                  $dt_sample_type[$data] = ''; 
                }

                // print the data on left-side (cell B-C)
                $objPHPExcel->setCellValue('B'.$rowPage, $dt_sampling_time[$data]);
                $objPHPExcel->setCellValue('C'.$rowPage, $dt_sample_type[$data]);

                // break the loop and..
                if ($data == 19  && $rowPage == 30 ) {
                    // print the data on right-side (cell D-E)
                    $objPHPExcel->setCellValue('D'.($rowPage-19), $dt_sampling_time[$data]);
                    $objPHPExcel->setCellValue('E'.($rowPage-19), $dt_sample_type[$data]);
                }                


                $data++;                
             }            


        }


      ?>
```

I'm working on Codeigniter and i want to export the data to Excel file (i'm using PHPExcel library), but i can't split the data like above table.
Above code won't print the data on Cell `D`and `E` but only printed on Cell `B` and `C`.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what do you means by `if ($data == 19  && $rowPage == 30 ) {`

Comment: I created `if condition` to stop the incremental loop, when increment `$data = 19` and increment `$rowPage = 30`, and then start again print the data on `Cell D and E (right-side)`

Comment: why used `$rowPage-19` ? why not use as usual `$rowPage`

Comment: I think after the break condition, i need to decrement the values by `19` to be able printed on cell `D` and `E`, but it doesn't work even if with usual `$rowPage`